# Apache nifi evaluateJsonPath splitJson

Tags: json, apache-nifi

With the ConvertRecord processor I have converted a csv text file to a json file which looks like this:

```
[
   {"A":1001,"B":"20170101","C":0.3},

   {"A":1001,"B":"20170102","C":0.1},
 .....]
```

I tried with evaluate Json Path to get the pathes like:

```
a: $.A
b: $.B
....
```

But I got only null values.

Im not sure do I need to split this JSON file with SplitJson processor before using evaluateJsonPath and when yes, what do I need to enter in the processor?

I tried

```
$.*
```

But it didn't work.

Or do I just need to use other JsonPath values in evaluateJsonPath processor?

Comment: it's not clear what is your goal..

Comment: Sorry, my goal is to save each value in cassandra. Means that I can place a cql statement in replace text processor like this:    insert into table (a, b, c) values ('${a}', '${b}', '${c}'). Hope that makes it clearer.

Answer (score 3):

thx for the answers.
I found the solution.
I had already the right way in my mind, so it was right to split the JSON at the path:

```
$.*
```

My mistake was a typo in the evaluateJsonPath processor.
So after splitting I could just evaluate the json path like this:

```
a: $.A
```

Answer (score 2):

Max,

You have to split json by using this expression `$[*]` in splitJSON Processor.

Afterwards you can use EvaluateJSONPath like expression `$.A ,$.B` to catch contents and so on.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

`$.A` assumes your JSON is only one object record.

You have a list.

`$[*].A` or `$..A` will return you a list of `[1001, 1001]` given your example